# Arrow annotation in an overcrowded scatterplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to annotate two points in a scatterplot, however due to the overcrowded nature, they become very difficult to see.

Is there anyway I can put an arrow or a pointer that points to the point in question but annotates the name in blank space away from the clustered observations?

[image]

```
plt.scatter(afb[:,0], afb[:,1], c="yellow")
plt.title("Arrow Scatter", weight="bold", fontsize=20)
plt.annotate("James", (a[812,0], a[812,1]))
plt.annotate("Jane", (a[1067,0], a[1067,1]))
plt.ylabel("2", fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel("1", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the location of the annotation text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xy = range(20)
plt.scatter(xy, xy, c='green', vmin=0, vmax=20, s=20)
plt.title("Arrow Scatter", weight="bold", fontsize=20)

# prep anno-text data
text_location = (2,15)
target_point = (xy[8],xy[8])

plt.annotate("Jane", target_point, text_location, 'data', \
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>", \
                connectionstyle="angle3", lw=1), \
                size=16, ha="center")

plt.ylabel("2", fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel("1", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Resulting image:
[image]